# mongooseim: how to use backend action from documentation for mod privacy as an example?

Tags: mongoose-im

Is it possible to use backend actions from this documentation for rest api or from command line?
https://esl.github.io/MongooseDocs/latest/modules/mod_privacy/

Also, I tried to use

```
[mod_privacy]
  default_list = "default_list"

[privacy_list.default_list]
  access = [{ allow = "roster" }]
```

in my configuration toml file but with no success..